# AJAX file upload with progress bar and input types

Tags: ajax, jquery

I need to submit form which contains two inputs:

```
<form action="upload" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" 

    id="upload">
            <textarea name="file_description"></textarea><br/>
            <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" /><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="upload_button" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

This question maybe duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery), but I tried and get errors. Can anyone guide me with submitting form which contains file and other inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XHR2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/) and [FileAPI](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). It's new HTML5 API with pretty good browser support by now. XHR2 allows you to send files via AJAX and FileAPI is used to get file content from input[type=file]

There are plenty articles on that subject in the web. For example: [Processing XHR2 file uploads in PHP](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/04/Processing-XHR2-file-uploads-in-PHP)